# Installing geopandas on Apple M1 chip

Tags: python, geopandas, apple-m1

How do you get `geopandas` to work in `python` with the new Apple M1 chip? Using `pip` does not work. I tried a lot of things and I think I came up with a work around that might be useful to others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I spent the better part of today figuring out how to get `geopandas` to work on a new Mac with the M1 chip. According to this [closed issue](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/issues/1816), you have to use conda ([miniconda3 FOR the M1 chip](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html)) to install geopandas on Apple's new M1 chip. I found that to be true, but incomplete. After installing miniconda3 and running

`conda install -c conda-forge geopandas pygeos`

Which will take you down to Python 3.8, I was still getting an error.

[image: error from trying to import geopandas]

Going into my `.../miniconda3/lib`, I found that there was a `libffi.8.dylib` file, but not a `libffi.7.dylib` file, so I just copied it `cp libffi.8.dylib libffi.7.dylib` and now python can import geopandas.

[image: picture showing the file missing and then copying a close version to the file needed]

[image: And now python can import geopandas.]

Hopefully that helps someone out there, or tell me why this workaround is not needed...